# Register Spotify intent-filters in manifest, Oreo

Tags: android, spotify

I can recieve the spotify and Google Music actions fine in Older versions of android, however in Android O I am unable to receive actions

Here is my Receiver declaration in the manifest

```
 <receiver
    android:name=".NextTrackReciever"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.music.playstatechanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.android.music.metachanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged"/>
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

In Oreo, the onReceive() in my Broadcast Receiver class doesnt fire. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0 and higher [restrict access to implicit broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). Your only choices are using scheduled jobs or starting a service with a persistent notification.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need register the broadcast receiver in your activity | fragment | service

In Android manifest file does not work as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val receiver = MyReceiver()

    val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.metadatachanged")
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
}
```